# Extract probabilities from Logistic Regression model by feature in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

I am currently using R and I'm looking to extract the probabilities by feature. How to accomplish this? For example, in Texas if feature A is false the probability of the class 1 is 65%. A python example will work as well, I can move over to Python.

```
model<-glm(formula = Class ~ .,data=data_frame,family = "binomial")
threshold=0.6
ifelse(predict(model,type="response")>threshold,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to fit a GLM model by removing the feature `A` from the predictors, since `A=F` is already observed, it's no longer a variable, and then use the relevant subset of the training dataset (filter with `A=F`) to train the GLM model, finally use the model for prediction, as shown in the example below:

```
# generate some data, let's assume for simplicity that the dataset contains 
# only two feature variables, namely A (binary) and B (numeric), 
# along with a binary response variable Class
n <- 100
set.seed(1)
data_frame <- data.frame(A=sample(c(T, F), n, replace = T), B=runif(n), 
                         Class=sample(0:1, n, replace = T))
head(data_frame)
#      A         B Class
#1  TRUE 0.6547239     1
#2 FALSE 0.3531973     1
#3  TRUE 0.2702601     0
#4  TRUE 0.9926841     1
#5 FALSE 0.6334933     1
#6  TRUE 0.2132081     1

# note that given A = F, so train the model with all variables except A 
# and only on the relevant training subset
threshold <- 0.6
model2 <- glm(formula = Class ~ .-A, data=data_frame[data_frame$A == F,], family = "binomial")
ifelse(predict(model2,type="response")>threshold,1,0)
# 2  5  9 10 16 17 18 19 27 30 31 32 34 37 39 40 41 42 44 45 46 47 48 51 53 54 57 58 59 62 63 64 65 66 67 69 70 71 72 76 77 80 81 82 86 88 90 93 
# 0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0 
# 94 98 99 
# 1  1  0
```